# How to hide menu arrow in Extjs Button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

According to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-arrow) of extjs 6.5, setting arrow property to false should hide the menu's arrow. I tried this and still can't hide the arrow. Is there any additinonal steps that I should make?

```
    var filterMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: menuItems
    });


    var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        iconCls: 'fa fa-filter',
        arrow: false, //this should disable
        menu: filterMenu
    });
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1K3J.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you reference the docs of the modern toolkit, but in your tags you tell you use classic toolkit (and the screenshot looks like classic as well).

The [`arrow`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#cfg-arrow) configuration you reference is only available in the modern toolkit.

The classic toolkit does not have an `arrow` configuration; instead, you may want to try the [`arrowVisible`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-arrowVisible) configuration.

Comment: Thank you, I am still new in Extjs, still getting used to toolkits.

Comment: You should, in the top right corner, switch off the modern toolkit ("M"), so that docs search only shows up results from classic.